# Weights based on distance

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

There is a triangle WES that is an equilateral triangle. There is a point D anywhere within a circle around WES.
Given three distances to points: DW, DS, DE (any positive number or 0)
I need to get a proportion, a "weight" of each point, so that the total always adds up to 1.
The shorter the distance, the larger the "weight".

For example, if DW = DS = DE they all should receive .333
If one of them is 0, it should receive 1, and others 0.
If two of the distances are the same, their weight should be the same,etc.

My first thought was to go sum all the distances and divide each by the sum, but that doesn't work since it's inverse relationship.
Please help me find a formula that can figure this out.

Comment: Something like [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) of $D$ in triangle $WES$?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin similar, but I think yours is way more complex than this problem. All of my points W, E, S are in an equaliteral triangle, and the point to which distance is calculated is anywhere within a circle drawn around this triangle

Comment: "that doesn't work since it's inverse relationship" okay, what if you do the same thing with inverses of lengths? Like suming up and dividing each inverse by the sum? Sprcial cases would be $0$-distances, but they clearly have $(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0),\,(0,0,1)$. Any properties should hold behind that mentioned in the question? E.g. it has to be one-to-one map, continious, sum of (weights multiplied by coordinates) should give coordinates of $D$ or so?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin
Thank you! I have arrived to same conlcusion like 1 minute before seeing your post. 
Yes, if I raise all distances to the -1 and then just do normal proportion ( DW / sum) it works out! The math is funky by hand, but the computer won't care. Have to watch out for those 0 though, of course!

Comment: It was a simple problem after all, I'm just stupid ':)

Comment: I like to compare with $0$ in programming like $|a-b|<\varepsilon$, where I take $\varepsilon$ something like $10^{-6}$. Hope that helps too. That's ok, see my previous question. Sometimes we all don't see obvious things.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's say the distances are $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$, and their corresponding weights $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$.

Let
$$w(d_1; d_2, d_3) = \begin{cases}
1, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 \gt 0 \\
1/2, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 = 0,~ d_3 \gt 0 \\ 
1/2, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
1/3, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 = 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
0, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_2 = 0 \\
0, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
\displaystyle \frac{ 1/d_2 + 1/d_3 }{ 2/d_1 + 2/d_2 + 2/d_3 }, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 \gt 0
\end{cases}$$
This has the following properties (for positive $\lambda$, $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$):
$$\begin{aligned}
w(d_1 ; d_2 , d_3) &= w(d_1 ; d_3 , d_2 ) \\
w(\lambda d_1 ; \lambda d_2 , \lambda d_3) &= w(d_1 ; d_2, d_3) \\
w(d_1 ; d_2 , d_3) + w(d_2 ; d_1 , d_3) + w(d_3 ; d_1, d_2) &= 1 \\
\end{aligned}$$
As an example, $w(2; 1, 1) = 4/10 = 0.4$, $w(1; 2, 1) = w(1; 1, 2) = 3/10 = 0.3$.

Then,
$$\begin{aligned}
w_1 &= w(d_1; d_2, d_3) \\
w_2 &= w(d_2; d_1, d_3) = w(d_2; d_3, d_1) \\
w_3 &= w(d_3; d_1, d_2) = w(d_3; d_2, d_1) \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

If you want the closest point emphasized more, you can use the generalized version,
$$w(d_1; d_2, d_3) = \begin{cases}
1, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 \gt 0 \\
1/2, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 = 0,~ d_3 \gt 0 \\ 
1/2, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
1/3, & d_1 = 0,~ d_2 = 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
0, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_2 = 0 \\
0, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_3 = 0 \\
\displaystyle \frac{ d_2^{-\omega} + d_3^{-\omega} }{ 2 \left( d_1^{-\omega} + d_2^{-\omega} + d_3^{-\omega} \right) }, & d_1 \gt 0,~ d_2 \gt 0,~ d_3 \gt 0
\end{cases}$$
where $1 \le \omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
For example, for $\omega = 2$, $w(2; 1, 1) = 8/18 \approx 0.4444$, and $w(1; 1, 2) = w(1; 2,1) = 5/18 \approx 0.2778$.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, I think it was way easier than that. It was solved in the comments under the post, I just didn't see an obvious easy solution.